# Can an SSRS Report show different components when printed?

Tags: reporting-services

Can elements of a report be hidden when viewed as a web page, but visible when the report is printed out (e.g. company logos, report file name, date of print, etc.)?

If it's possible, how would it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a global variable **RenderFormat.IsInteractive** to determine if the format is web or report manager.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive = TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```